# Can i post information on a Facebook Group Wall using a Facebook Application in C#

Tags: c#, facebook

Can i post information on a Facebook Group Wall using a Facebook Application in C#

Answer (score 2):

You cannot post on Group Walls.

You can post on User Walls or Public Profile Walls. Not Group Walls.

Answer (score 2):

If you have permissions I think you can use the the [Graph Api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api) to do http://graph.facebook.com/GROUP_ID/feed and [Post](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post) on the feed

[Here is a library for the facebook graph api](http://hernan.amiune.com/labs/facebook/c-sharp-facebook-graph-api-library.html)